# Questions about a pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

A pendulum is swinging. I am reading about the way it moves (regards the law of conservation of energy), and if I understand correctly, the max speed is reached when the pendulum passes through the equilibrium position $(2)$, and then the velocity begins to decrease. At position $1$ and $3$ the velocity is equal to $0$, right? Is $h$ the maximum deviation from the equilibrium position?

[image]

Comment: At 1 and 3 velocity must vanish since it is inverting its sign. h is the maximum *vertical* displacement from equilibrium position. Why do not you build your own pendulum with a mass attached to a string just to *observe* directly what the book is describing? Many things could become much more clear in reality than in a written page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since positions $1$ and $3$ are the positions where the velocity of the pendulum is zero, these are the positions where all of the kinetic energy has been converted into potential energy. Thus, these are the positions where the pendulum achieves a maximum height, or, a maximum deviation from the equilibrium.